# Play mp3 file after uploading it with html5 drag and drop upload

Tags: javascript, api, audio, google-chrome, mozilla

Is it possible to first upload an mp3 file with the html5 drag and drop upload system, and then play it with webkit's audio API (http://chromium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/samples/audio/index.html) without submitting a form (in Google Chrome)? Is it possible to do in FF with Mozilla's audio API? If so, how? Also, are  there any tutorials in existance for webkit's API? I have not been able to find any.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The basic process you need to follow is

1. Capture the files using [Drag and Drop Files](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/dnd/basics/#toc-dnd-files)
2. Posting the files in a [Form Data Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest)
3. Respond with the URL of the audio item you want to play
4. Play the Audio using the Audio API

This [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gaJyT/18/) allows you to drag an audio file into an area and it will then play that file.

You should be able to use the [JavaScriptAudioNode](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/audio/raw-file/tip/webaudio/specification.html#JavaScriptAudioNode-section)'s onaudioprocess event to get the current amplitude.

**Edit:**

Based on what [JaapH](https://stackoverflow.com/users/252441/jaaph) said I had a look into this again. The processor was used to get an appropriate event to render the canvas. So it is not really required. This [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gaJyT/40/) does the same as below. However, it uses [requestAnimationFrame](http://paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/) instead of the processor.

Here is the old code, see the fiddle above for the version using request animation frame:

```
var context = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();
var source;
var processor;
var analyser;
var xhr;

function initAudio(data) {
    source = context.createBufferSource();

    if(context.decodeAudioData) {
        context.decodeAudioData(data, function(buffer) {
            source.buffer = buffer;
            createAudio();
        }, function(e) {
            console.log(e);
        });
    } else {
        source.buffer = context.createBuffer(data, false /*mixToMono*/);
        createAudio();
    }
}

function createAudio() {
    processor = context.createJavaScriptNode(2048 /*bufferSize*/, 1 /*num inputs*/, 1 /*numoutputs*/);
    processor.onaudioprocess = processAudio;
    analyser = context.createAnalyser();

    source.connect(context.destination);
    source.connect(analyser);

    analyser.connect(processor);
    processor.connect(context.destination);

    source.noteOn(0);
    setTimeout(disconnect, source.buffer.duration * 1000);
}

function disconnect() {
    source.noteOff(0);
    source.disconnect(0);
    processor.disconnect(0);
    analyser.disconnect(0);
}

function processAudio(e) {
    var freqByteData = new Uint8Array(analyser.frequencyBinCount);
    analyser.getByteFrequencyData(freqByteData);
    console.log(freqByteData);
}

function handleResult() {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4 /* complete */) {
        switch(xhr.status) {
            case 200: /* Success */
                initAudio(request.response);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        xhr = null;
    }      
}

function dropEvent(evt) {
    evt.stopPropagation();
    evt.preventDefault();

    var droppedFiles = evt.dataTransfer.files;

    //Ajax the file to the server and respond with the data

    var formData = new FormData();
    for(var i = 0; i < droppedFiles.length; ++i) {
            var file = droppedFiles[i];

            files.append(file.name, file);
    }

    xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST", 'URL');  
    xhr.onreadystatechange = handleResult;
    xhr.send(formData);
}

function dragOver(evt) {
    evt.stopPropagation();
    evt.preventDefault();
    return false;
}

var dropArea = document.getElementById('dropArea');
dropArea.addEventListener('drop', dropEvent, false);
dropArea.addEventListener('dragover', dragOver, false);
```

I hope this helps

Comment: That would work fine, but I NEED to play it with webkit's audio API and/or Mozilla's. Or, if there was a way to get the current amplitude of something playing in an audio tag, that would work too. Also, don't assume people are using jquery.

Comment: Ok. I have taken out jquery code and update the answer to use the Audio API. This [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gaJyT/11/) has all the Audio API code but it uses the file reader instead of AJAX. There is a lot more in the code now. Let me know if I need to explain it better.

Comment: When I run the jsfiddle example the sound is distorted this is due that both the processor and source are connected to context.destination.

Comment: I have not been able to reproduce any problems with distorted sounds. However, if you are only looking to animate the frequency data, I added an edit that shows using requestAnimationFrame instead of the processor.

Comment: I've updated the fiddle, it seems to not work due to audio api updates. This should make it functional: http://jsfiddle.net/gaJyT/182/

Answer (score 1):

When I run the jsfiddle example the sound is distorted this is due that both the processor and source are connected to context.destination. To get it to work I removed the line `source.connect(context.destination);` and in the `processAudio` function I added code to copy the input samples to the output

```
var inL = e.inputBuffer.getChannelData(0);
var inR = e.inputBuffer.getChannelData(1);
var outL= e.outputBuffer.getChannelData(0);
var outR =e.outputBuffer.getChannelData(1);

var n = inL.length;
for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    outL[i] = inL[i];
    outR[i] = inR[i];
}
```