# Is there a library that abstracts Web Audio API and Mozilla Audio Data API for reading raw audio (MP3,ogg)

Tags: html, firefox, google-chrome, browser, html5-audio

I want to do some audio visualizations, that read raw ogg or mp3 data and use it with dsp.js. Is there a library that embraces and abstracts  googles and Mozillas Audio API and ideally safari and others ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7700273/play-mp3-file-after-uploading-it-with-html5-drag-and-drop-upload, this post has the answer for your question.

Comment: No sorry. My question points more in the direction of analyzing the data like with DSP.js or Beatdetector.js or similar and getting the frequencies and BPM etc. Means access to the raw audio data of the file. Currently (as far as I understood) it can be done in both now, ff and chrome, but the APIs have both a different approach. What I am looking for is a library that would cover both. I would start it myself, but I am not that good in JS yet.

Comment: Ok. Please describe more about  `DSP.js or Beatdetector.js or similar and getting the frequencies and BPM`in your question & change the tags.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I think the tags are ok, because I am not looking for a dsp alike solution. It is just an example. dsp.js is using fast fourier transformation on the read and to be analyzed audiomaterial provided by the mozilla audiodata and beat detector I beleave uses the peaks.[link](https://github.com/corbanbrook/dsp.js). It wont work in chrome, because it uses the moz audiodata api. I guess you can do the same with the newest chrome web audio api. What I am looking for is a library or JS that combines the mozilla audioda and the chrome audiosource api.

Comment: Moz: [link](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Audio_Data_API) Chrome:[link](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/audio/raw-file/tip/webaudio/specification.html#AudioSourceNode-section) and depending on the user agent it uses this or that way to read the raw audio

Comment: the most promising library candidate to add this abstraction seems to be soundmanager2.js [link](http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/) which contains a similar functionality. But the raw audio reading is currently done by flash only, while the whole API is HTML5 Audio and Flash (as a fallback).

Comment: audiolib.js wraps both web audio API and moz audio data API, can load samples, and wraps fft.js for FFT analysis: https://github.com/jussi-kalliokoski/audiolib.js

Answer (score 2):

have a look at https://wiki.mozilla.org/Audio_Data_API#JavaScript_Audio_Libraries

Comment: simply putting a link is not enough, please provide some more info what is on that page you referring to.

Answer (score 0):

take a look at: [KievII - An Audio/DSP JavaScript Library For Web & Mobile Audio Applications](http://www.functionn.in/2013/01/kievii-audiodsp-javascript-library-for.html)

Comment: The link seems to be broken?