# Loading audio directly into DOM

Tags: javascript, html5-audio

I would like for the user to be able to upload an audio file of their choice, and play it back using HTML/JS. This upload can be a once-only deal, it does not need to be persistent. I know I can accomplish this by loading the file first to the server, then serving it again.

Is there an easier way to directly load it into the DOM in an audio tag without having to go through the server? I know in general you are prevented from loading resources on a domain other than your own, but just thought I would ask.

Comment: See : 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7700273/play-mp3-file-after-uploading-it-with-html5-drag-and-drop-upload

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way is a Flash or Java Applet...

Otherwise jo need a server-side implementation. If you only want to use js and html, try this:
http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/