# How to convert opus readable stream to PCM or .wav file in node.js?

Tags: node.js, npm, pcm, opus

I have opus readable stream I want to save that into file with .wav extension using fs module.
any **working** node.js module/npm package?

node v12.0.0

Comment: opus format has been encoded. To convert that encoded format to PCM ( wav) is going to require mux step ( decode opus ,  render PCM , apply wav headers ). "fluent" is node module that can do the muxing steps.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10040317/getting-raw-pcm-data-from-webaudio-mozaudio  ans here may be of help